# simple captcha instllation problems on rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed SimpleCaptcha plugin to vendor/plugin

For the setup the plugin I am getting

> rake simple_captcha:setup
>   Gives me error: rake aborted!
>   Don't know how to build task 'simple_captcha:setup'

I checked rails version by

> gem list
>   rails (3.1.3)
>   railties (3.1.3)
>   rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
>
> ruby -v
>   ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

I am looking for help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include simplecaptcha gem in GemFile as below

```
gem "galetahub-simple_captcha", :require => "simple_captcha"
```

Visit https://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha